# Change FancyBox overlay image function

Tags: jquery, fancybox, overlay

**FancyBox overlay problem:**

Our company would purchase commercial license(s) if we could get a solution to what seems right off to be a simple problem. In our current lightbox we can change the overlay to display a different background image which complements each video displayed in the lightbox. Because the overlay is an ID it is easily accomplished with an `onclick` in the  tag:

```
function myfunction() {
    document.getElementById("lightbox-overlay").style.backgroundImage="url('image.jpg')";
}
```

However, the fancybox overlay is defined with a class:

```
.fancybox-overlay { background: url('fancybox_overlay.png'); }
```

We are not coding experts, but have googled our keys off looking for a solution. We like fancybox because of its built-in responsiveness.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've tagged this JQuery but the code is all plain JS or CSS that you've mentioned; if using JQuery that is extremely simple - otherwise it is somewhat harder but nothing impossible. So which version would you prefer?

Comment: I used jquery as a tag as advised by fancybox support; fancybox is apparently manipulated by jquery. My code was merely a simplified example of how our current lightbox overlays can be changed by clicking on thumbnail images.

Answer (score 0):

Totally doable. One approach would be to use a data attribute w/ the correct image you'd like to use as the background image.

On the Fancybox trigger:

```
<a class="fancybox-media" rel="fancybox-button" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo" title="Example" data-img="URL to your Image">
```

Then, use one of the callbacks from the fancybox API, such as 'beforeLoad' which is 'Called before starting to load content.'

```
$(".fancybox-media").fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
        var backgroundImg = $(this.element).attr('data-img');
        $('.fancybox-inner').css('background', 'url(' + backgroundImg + ')');
    }
});
```

It'll obviously require some CSS styling effort on your side, just make sure to include the relevant CSS after the Fancybox CSS and you should be able to integrate this pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I tried the function as is and substituting .fancybox-inner with .fancybox-overlay which I believe controls the background "behind" fancybox. Neither worked, so I'm thinking the beforeload function is not being recognized, even though I've called in all fancybox files on the page. I still get the default overlay.Your suggestion seems entirely logical, and I'll dig into why the function is not working.

Comment: Make sure that you're using the correct version of Fancybox, and following the implementation steps they have provided on their site. Run some tests, log the value to the console for instance before attempting any CSS changes. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/